# Take array element text before element containing specific text

Tags: java

I'm getting specific project name based on the folder root. Using the code:

```
private String getProjectName(Scenario scenario) {
    List<String> pathArray = Arrays.asList(Path.of(scenario.getUri()).toUri().getPath().split("/"));
    return pathArray.get(pathArray.size() - 1);
}
```

For such structure as it's shown on below screenshot it works. However, when more then one folder before .feature (number 9) file name will be added then it will fail.

[image: Folder root]

My idea is to:

1. Get the index of an array which contains text: "features"
2. Move to the next index (project name) and get the proper text + return it

Is it good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your method to return the split value after "features".

```
private String getProjectName(Scenario scenario) {
    String desiredString = "features";
    String[] pathArray = Path.of(scenario.getUri()).toUri().getPath().split("/");
    for (int i = 0; i < pathArray.length; i++) {
        if (pathArray[i].equals(desiredString)) {
            return (pathArray[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("The url provided does not contain <%s>", desiredString));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you do not know how nested your folder structure is, you need some pattern to recognize the element that you know will exist in the project structure, in your example with "features" text, and then move to the next index. So your idea looks fine to me.

Comment: Any hints how I may start with this?